# Kafka as DB cache

Tags: java, apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have 5 kafka topics where 100 msgs will flow every second.Message format is below

{null,JSON} (partitions :10)

I need to pull a record from the past based on a value within JSON and process in my java application. What would be the correct approach ?

1. ksqlDB Streams
2. Kafka Streams
3. Ktable

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4):

While it's possible to use Kafka as a DB, **I highly encourage you not to go for that approach**. Kakfa is a message broker, so if you want to peek a message from the past **you'll have to reprocess the whole topic**

The only scenario in which you may be able to handle the situation "gracefully" would be if you knew the offset of the message so you can set your consumers to go directly there, but due to the use case you described I don't think you have it

I haven't work with ksqlDB but it looks like regular KQSL

KSQL is just an abstraction on top of Kafka Streams, the same way as Kafka Streams is an abstraction over a consumer-producer. Each abstraction has less capabilities

You could achieve your objective using any approach you want, beware that there are several factors that will make you choose one or another, for example

- KSQL is the simplest approach but you need a KSQL server
- (AFAIK) KSQL doesn't work with all serialization formats
- Kafka Streams is best suited when you have an ETL scenario (read from Kafka, process the message, send back to Kafka)
- If you need full control of the flow, a regular consumer-producer will give it to you

Comment: OK, looks like KSQL was evolved into KSQLDB (https://www.confluent.io/blog/intro-to-ksqldb-sql-database-streaming/), so I'd need to research a bit about the new capabilities. Maybe the Pull Queries do what you need, but again, I'd not use Kafka as a DB

Answer (score 3):

First of all, think about what you want to achieve in your application. If you want DB capabilities, like complex joins, using stored procedure and so on, then Kafka it's not the choice (even if Kafka can do complex joins, but with a more complex code written by you).

Your scenarios seems to be suitable for a `Kafka Streams` topology, where you can use a materialized `KTable` (in fact a `Store`) which will allow you to find data via a partition key. The performance will be the same as on top of a database, because the `Store` it's materialized into a `RocksDB` database.

Keep in mind that for doing this you will face all the issues that are common when you do partitioning (first of all, finding a common partition key for all data items).

You can find more details about how `Kafka Streams` work here: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/architecture.html and about `Kafka Store`: https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/state/Stores.html.